# Benefit of using bitwise AND operator between integers?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I was looking at some code which is like:

```
public int someMethod(String path, int maxCallers) {

        int hash = path.hashCode();
        int caller = (hash & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % maxCallers;
        return caller;
    }
```

This method returns which caller to be called based on the path. If the `maxCallers` value is 4 the caller value should be between 0-3. Now here i don't understand the use of doing `hash & Integer.MAX_VALUE`. One reason i can think of is the programmer wants a positive number as hashcode can be negative, but i think my understanding is wrong here. Can someone please explain the use of bitwise AND operator here.

Comment: "One reason i can think of is the programmer wants a positive number as hashcode can be negative, but i think my understanding is wrong here." Your understanding is actually right. That's the fastest way of dropping the sign bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. It's to remove the sign of the integer in case the hash is negative. `AND`ing with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` will remove the sign bit from the integer. Note that this is different from getting the absolute value of the integer:

```
int hash = -1;
int caller = (hash & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % 4;  // returns 3

int hash = -1;
int caller = Math.abs(hash) % 4;  // returns 1
```

Comment: thanks for replying.Can there be any other approach to it? Or is this a faster way?

Comment: Yes it is fastest way to remove the sign bit.

Comment: Yes i noted that also, the Math.abs wasn’t used here. Could be trying to same himself from the Integer.MIN_VALUE case. If the hashcode is Integer.MIN_VALUE

Comment: Yes indeed for this value, `Math.abs` cannot be used.